# ASP.NET Core RC2 SMTP Client

Tags: asp.net-core, mailkit, .net-core-rc2

The new ASP.NET Core framework does not include the System.Net.Mail namespace from the full .NET framework. The RC1 version did have support for MailKit & MimeKit, so using that sending emails was possible, but with the recently released RC2 `System.Net.Security.SslStream` no longer includes `AuthenticateAsClient(System.String, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols, Boolean)`

And all calls to that function should be replaced with `AuthenticateAsClientAsync`

This causes Mailkit to throw a `MissingMethodException`. Mailkit will probably be updated soon, but I currently cannot find a way to send emails with the new RC2 release.

So I was wondering did anyone find another implementation of SmtpClient that does support `ASP.NET Core RC2`?

Comment: Grab the sources, make the necessary changes, do a pull request and contribute to it? :) https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit